# All Desktop Icons have disappeared

Tags: windows-7, desktop, icons

My Windows7-german-64bit installation worked fine until today.

But this morning I have suddenly lost all my desktop icons.

I can re-enable the icons via

```
              right-click on desktop > Ansicht > Desktop Symbole anzeigen)
(translation: right-click on desktop > View    > Show Desktop Icons)
```

But on logoff/logon the icons are lost again!

Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: Correct translation would be *Show Desktop Icons* :)

Comment: Actually, they haven't "disappeared". Like you indicated, they are coming back when checking this "Show Desktop Icons". This is a feature from the desktop. Your problem is rather why this feature is active, and most of all, why it is not saving the status when you log out.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed all Windows updates?

I had this problem at first (WIn 7 64 bit) but with recent updates it has cured itself.